# Can you omit the last word if it would be twice behind each other?

Tags: attribute

The question is about the following sentence:

> Darüber hinaus können Ereignisse auch von Zeituhren, dies können beispielsweise einmalige Termine, sein.

AFAIK the attribute of "Zeituhren" should be "...Zeituhren, dies können beispielsweise einmalige Termine **sein**, sein". Am I wrong here? Is there any special rule, so you can omit the last verb if it would be there twice?

Comment: Are the “einmalige Termine” an example of “Ereignisse” or “Zeituhren” ?

Comment: @Stephie "einmalige Termine" are an example for "Zeituhren"

Comment: Rephrasing, so that you don't need to repeat it, would be an alternative imho.

Comment: Regardless of grammar, you shouldn't nest sentences too deep.

Comment: but the question __is__ about grammar, not about best practices

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, omitting verbs is not valid, just because they would be repeated. In the given example the verb is required on each side of the comma.

Practically this the question appears quite seldom. In your example the verb corresponding to *Ereignisse* should probably read *herrühren*, *stammen* or similar. There are other options like shortening the subordinate clause to *beispielsweise einmalige Termine*.